# How to move content from a textarea to a div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, swap

I want to move content from a `<textarea>` to a `<div>` and I don't really know how to do it.

this is my code:

```
<div id=one>
   <textarea id="mssg" rows="5" cols="40" >
       Hey, I am cooking. what are you doing?
   </textarea>
   <br>
</div>
<input type="button" value="swap" onclick="swap()">
<a href="solution.html" >Sign out</a>
<div id="two" >
    <div>Sent messages appear here:</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function swap()
    {
        var one = document.getElementById("one").innerHTML;
        two.innerHTML = "<div>"+one+"</div>";
    }
</script>
```

[Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwI3T.jpg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function swap()
{
    var one = document.getElementById("one").innerHTML;

    var two = document.getElementById("two");
    var twohtml = document.getElementById("two").innerHTML
    document.getElementById('one').remove();
    two.innerHTML =   "<div>"+twohtml+"</div>" + "<div>"+one+"</div>" ;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function swap() {
         var one = document.getElementById("one");
         var one_inner = one.innerHtml;
         var two = document.getElementById("two");

         one.innerHtml = two.innerHtml;
         two.innerHtml = one_inner;

     }
</script>
```

It is a weird behaviour, really. Anyway, you are swapping contents, not elements.

I hope it helps.